# MobX: Update observable value in autorunAsync action

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Sources [here](https://github.com/mr-wildcard/mobx-react-giphy/tree/develop) on `develop` branch.

In this simple app, I use `autorunAsync` to debounce `searchText` updates and fetch Giphy API accordingly. Everything works fine until I want to display a simple loader next to the input while a request is processing.

Uncommenting [this line](https://github.com/mr-wildcard/mobx-react-giphy/blob/develop/src/store/searchModel.js#L25) ends up with the action being fired infinitely.

[image]

I thought that `autorun` and `autorunAsync` would fire the action only when the targeted observable is modified. (`searchText` in my case)

How to combine both side effects (like API fetching) and state update within the same action ? I tried `transaction`, but I couldn't make it work either..
I need more time to wrap my head around MobX concept and I'm sure this is a stupid mistake. :)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is correct. This was actually a bug in `autorunAsync`. MobX 2.0.2 should fix this issue.